# How to login a user in AWS Cognito if user clicked Forgot password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Forget Password option in AWS Cognito currently takes user's status to FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD status, but till user does not complete the process user cannot login again with the old password.

For the scenarios:

1. When someone click forgot password and do not have access to email or mobile he might not login with the old password.
2. Anyone can use other's email id to call forgot password and that other person can not login.

Please let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed aws cli? If so then you can use

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-reset-user-password.html

to resend the confirmation

```
[resend-confirmation-code]
```

to reset the user's password

```
[admin-reset-user-password]
```

then

```
[admin-initiate-auth]
```

followed by

```
[admin-respond-to-auth-challenge]
```

as in

```
aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --user-pool-id us-east-Example --client-id 7gef0qeet4kgik2jqmjExample --auth-flow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=user,PASSWORD=password
```

this is to set the status flag to confirmed from force changed password

then

```
aws cognito-idp admin-respond-to-auth-challenge --user-pool-id us-east-Example --client-id 7gef0qeet4kgik2jqmjExample --challenge-name NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED --challenge-responses NEW_PASSWORD=newpassword,USERNAME=chris --session "%the session token you just generated%"
```

replace %the session token you just generated" with what comes as the output from the first command.